# How to draw a 2d image in java/android studio using OpenGL ES 2.0?

Tags: android, 2d, textures, opengl-es-2.0, draw

I've been trying(for a couple weeks now) to draw a 2d image using opengl and I just can't seem to get it right. I am very experienced with coding with java/android studio but it's the first time I need to use opengl.

I know how to draw any shape I want and fill it with any color, but, I just can't draw the texture.

I believe the problem is either in the draw() or the shaders.

This is the draw function of a Sprite Object:

```
GLES20.glUseProgram(shader.program);
GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

int position = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(shader.program, "position");
int color_uniform = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(shader.program, "color");
int tex_position = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(shader.program, "a_tex_coords");
int texture_uniform = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(shader.program, "texture");

vertex_buffer.position(0);
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(position, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 2 * 4, vertex_buffer);
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(position);

texture_buffer.position(0);
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(tex_position, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 2 * 4, texture_buffer);
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(tex_position);

GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.texture_id);
GLES20.glUniform1i(texture_uniform, 0);

GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, index_buffer);

GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(position);
```

These are my vertex / fragment shader codes:

```
private final String vertexShaderCode =
"attribute vec4 position;" +
"attribute vec2 a_tex_coords;" +
"varying vec2 v_tex_coords;" +
"void main() {" +
"   gl_Position = position;" +
"   v_tex_coords = a_tex_coords;" +
"}";

String fragmentShaderCode =
"precision mediump float;" +
"uniform vec4 color;" +
"uniform sampler2D texture;" +
"varying vec2 v_tex_coords;" +
"void main() {" +
"   gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, v_tex_coords) * color;" +
"}";
```

Comment: What does it look like when you draw it?

Comment: Likely you have to set `color`. The default value of `color` is (0, 0, 0, 1).

Comment: Where do you set the uniform variable `color`?